# How to check empty/null CSV value?

Tags: powershell

The following code

```
"a,b,c
1,1,1
2,,2
3,3,3" > test.csv

import-csv test.csv | select b | % { 
    Write-Host "$_ $([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))" 
}
```

returns

```
@{b=1} False
@{b=} False
@{b=3} False
```

However, I expected the second line return `True`. I tried `$_ -eq $null -or $_ -eq ''` and none if them work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that inside of the `% { }` block `$_` does not contain the value of column `b` but rather an object with a `b` property.  When you run `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)` you are testing if this object is null or an empty string, neither of which is true.

To illustrate what's happening, compare the results of...

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | Get-Member
```

...with the results of...

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | select b | Get-Member
```

...with the results of...

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | select -ExpandProperty b | Get-Member
```

One solution is to test if the `b` property of the object produced by `select` (rather than the object itself) is null or empty:

```
import-csv test.csv | select b | % { 
    Write-Host "$_ $([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.b))" 
}
```

Another solution is to pass only the value of column `b` to the `% { }` block:

```
import-csv test.csv | select -ExpandProperty b | % { 
    Write-Host "$_ $([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_))" 
}
```

Comment: AHhhh took my answer out from underneath me.

Comment: @Matt My name is Matt, too.  We were predisposed to answer this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code works.

```
import-csv test.csv | select b | % { 
    Write-Host "$_ $($_.b -eq '')" 
}
```

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your example in the question there is still an object present with an empty `b` parameter. Consider the following which shows why you got the result you did.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> @{} -eq $null
False
```

The rest of this would be to expand the property much like in [Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081475/3829407)